# Is there a way to make sure I can only open a world with a specific profile?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today the first 1.7 snapshot came out and with it a bunch of new biome and terrain features. I want to check it out, but I'm afraid if I open one of my existing worlds while using the snapshot I'll create ugly chunk borders.

To try to prevent that, I created a new profile in the launcher so I can tell whether I'm using 1.6 or a snapshot; however, I can still open an old world in the snapshot if I'm not paying attention. Is there any way to either make sure specific worlds can only be opened with specific profiles or to use different save folders for different profiles so the worlds are kept separate?

Comment: create a backup of your .minecraft folder, or open the 1.7 world in a whitelisted server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! And very easily, too. Profiles allow you to tell Minecraft where to store all its files by changing the **Game Directory** option in the profile. Just add something memorable onto the Game Directory (such as `1.7-snapshots`) and that profile will never see your existing worlds.

How this works is, setting this to a different folder than the default .minecraft folder makes the game keep an almost entirely separate Minecraft install in the specified folder. (The only thing it doesn't keep separate is the game code itself – this is still drawn from the `.minecraft/versions/` folder, which as you've found works just fine and doesn't compromise firewalling different installs.)

I use this myself to maintain multiple private modpacks separately from the main Minecraft version, and they co-exist perfectly and peacefully within the official launcher. It means that there is absolutely no danger of accidentally opening a modded world while running vanilla Minecraft (and thereby destroying the save!) or vice versa. I make it easy on myself by simply adding `modpacks/[name-of-modpack]` onto the end of the default Game Directory, which neatly stores all my modded Minecraft stuff in a "modpacks" folder within my .minecraft folder.

Comment: Just went to take advantage of this (since I hadn't known 1.7 snapshots were out!) and of course the very first world seed I pick (`The New World`) is an tiny but well-treed island stranded in the middle of the new Deep Ocean biome.

Comment: You can't be *too* stranded, now, according to the [latest biome changes](https://mojang.com/2013/08/minecraft-world-generator-update/). ;-)

Comment: @dlras2 I read that! But this strange new world is unknown enough that I daren't set out without some investigation. My digging adventure went about as expected, but my fishing efforts are decidedly new in outcome! Maybe I'll set sail once I gather provisions.

Comment: That sounds like the beginning of an epic blog... which perhaps you should start!

Comment: @dlras2 I started playing Minecraft after reading some of Towards Dawn, so I know just what you mean! I had the same thought, even. Alas, the time to write it and do it justice just isn't there. :)